# Install package programmatically with Merge-Append

Tags: packages

I'm trying to develop a small utility that installs an uploaded Sitecore package.
This tool should only install using the `Merge-Append` option.

This [article](http://sitecoreblog.blogspot.com/2012/11/install-sitecore-package-in-your-code.html) uses `Overwrite`.
Could you please help me understand what the first argument is for, in the `BehaviourOptions` method.

I want unavailable items to be created & existing items to be merged by adding a new version (`Merge-Append`).
For that, will this be the right code.

```
Sitecore.Install.Items.IItemInstallerEvents events =
       new Sitecore.Install.Items.DefaultItemInstallerEvents(
           new Sitecore.Install.Utils.BehaviourOptions(Sitecore.Install.Utils.InstallMode.Merge, 
 Sitecore.Install.Utils.MergeMode.Append));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First parameter is `InstallMode` which can be one of 3:

- Overwrite
- Merge
- Skip

Second parameter is `MergeMode`, only valid for `Merge` `InstallMode`. Values can be:

- Merge
- Append
- Overwrite

It's the same like if you choose options in UI. When you select `Merge`, you can select another option from the dropdown:

[image]

I found the image and more information here: https://sitecorecorner.wordpress.com/2015/04/29/sitecore-package-installation-learnings/

Or here:

https://www.partech.nl/nl/publicaties/2012/11/sitecore-package-installation-options-explained

Comment: In my understanding, both the arguments in the BehaviourOptions method are only for the case of existing items. Is that correct.

Comment: Yes, if an item is not there, the option doesn't matter.